# crop image in ActiveX dll with vb6

Tags: image, vb6, crop

i'm using vb6 to build an ActiveX to process image with resize / crop operation.

about crop image, the marjor method is place two picture boxes, then

```
Form1.Picture2.PaintPicture Form1.Picture1.Image, 0, 0, wid, hgt, m_X1, m_Y1, wid, hgt
```

is ok when in exe project, but in activex, is rasing error with 'ASP 0115' C0000005 (using in ASP classic), so how can I fix this problem? or is there another way to crop image in vb6, thanks!

Comment: finnaly, i'm using `GdipCloneBitmapAreaI` to realize image croping cause the project using gdi+ then had better to keep it, but i still thanx that your suggest about `WIA 2.0`, it looks using it is quite easy, i'll try it in next time, thanks again. btw, why you post your reply not answer but comment, so i can tag your reply as this question's answer;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are after a way to do this in classic ASP, you might take a look at the WIA 2.0 Automation Library. This is part of Vista and later and until recently you could download a redist version for back-porting into the now-near-death WinXP (SP1 or later). Scaling and cropping are just two of the things you can use this for.